# Access first record of table in Rails Console Results in NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 3.2.12 and Roby 2.0.0-p0 in RVM etc. In `rails console` I get the following error after doing `u = Users.first`:

```
u = Users.first
Loading production environment (Rails 3.2.12)
2.0.0p0 :001 > u = Users.first
NoMethodError: undefined method `first' for Users:Module
    from (irb):1
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@discourse/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@discourse/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@discourse/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I was able to access the database and view the record via the psql console using the user rails would be using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have a User model defined, try User.first instead of Users.first.

Comment: Damn, one Ruby newb here. Five minutes ago I would wave sworn I'd already tried that. :)

Comment: I will, but I have to wait a couple more minutes as there is a time limit.